# Separate SQL query from concatenate?

Tags: sql, sqlite, concatenation

Using the following sqlite data:

| startn | rel | endn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turner syndrome | assoc | horseshoe kidneys |

I'm trying to use this statement:

```
select '{"id": "' || endn from dx_graph where startn='Turner syndrome' || '"},'
```

To generate this kind of result:
`{"id": "horseshoe kidneys"},`

But instead it throws an error because I think it's searching for `startn='Turner syndrome"},'`, which is not what I want.

How can I get around this?

Comment: What exact output do you want here?

Comment: Do you just want `select '{"id": "' || endn  || '"},' from dx_graph where startn='Turner syndrome'`?

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thanks Fred. Very helpful! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Or may be not to reinvent the wheel and face escaping problems just use [`json_object`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jobj) function.

Comment: Ahh that seems like a super useful function! Thanks.